# How to check if service exists in services.msc and iff it exists add dependency on that service[conditionally]

Tags: windows-services, dependencies

I do have my own service named ExchangeOfData. which is dependent on the Sqlexpress services.
I do have issue of when I restarts the system, sqlexpress is stopped or on few machines it does not exist it won't be working as expected. As it fails to communicate with database.

I want to know how can we check :

1. is "Sqlexpress" service exists or not.
2. if exists then only add dependency.

Please guide me on this. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: i think this would probably help http://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed

Comment: I have tried "DependOnService" but If the service does not exists, then how to track it?